# Using postgres database from another computer

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgresql-9.5, remote, pg-hba.conf

I have PostgreSQL version 9.5 installed at my machine (Windows 7 Enterprise x64 bit version). I have several databases in schema 'public'. I would like to use/access one of these databases from another machine (Windows 7) using LAN connectivity (so that this database may act as a shared database between two machines). I was wondering whether is it possible to do through "listen_addresses" option in postgresql.conf dialogue window? If not, is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: You need to edit `pg_hba.conf`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 4):

Read the article [Configuring PostgreSQL to Accept Connections From Computers on Your Network](http://help.bluemangolearning.com/m/screensteps-workgroup/l/18259-Configuring-PostgreSQL-to-Accept-Connections-From-Computers-on-Your-Network) where it is explained with screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, two things that need to happen:

1. Your database must be listening on a port and ip to external connections. For this you need to modify `postgresql.conf`, you may choose to use the new-ish method of [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) to do that.
2. Your database must be properly configured to authenticate someone coming in externally. To do this you must add a host or preferably `hostssl` entry in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for that ip/port.